# How to import adjacent module when running .hs file as script

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I was following the directions here:
https://haskell.fpcomplete.com/tutorial/stack-script

I have a cabal/stack project with this file structure:

```
app/Main.hs
src/Lib.hs
```

I can run Main.hs with:

```
stack runghc -- app/Main.hs
```

that works if Main.hs does not import Lib.hs, but if it does, I get this error:

```
app/Main.hs:3:1: error:
    Ambiguous module name ‘Lib’:
      it was found in multiple packages:
      haskell-starter-0.1.0.0 libiserv-8.6.3
  |
3 | import Lib
  | ^^^^^^^^^^
```

is there anyway to include the src/Lib.hs file in the build? For a package it would look like:

```
stack runghc --package xyz -- app/Main.hs
```

but what about for a module or file? Something like:

```
stack runghc --module src/Lib.hs -- app/Main.hs
```

?

**Update**: So I tried this:

```
stack runghc -- -i src/* app/Main.hs
```

And I got:

> ```
> src/Lib.hs:0:66: error:
>     • Variable not in scope: main :: IO a0
>     • Perhaps you meant ‘min’ (imported from Prelude)
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `runghc` the `-i` option to tell it about include paths. The following should work:

```
stack runghc -- -isrc app/Main.hs
```

Comment: I tried this and putting a space between `-i lib` and neither worked..hmmm...what's the rhyme/reason in this command

Comment: I think you might have meant `stack runghc -- -i src/* app/Main.hs` but that didn't work, I got the error in the updated OP

Comment: I made a typo, did you try -isrc?

Comment: yeah `-isrc` worked, what's the explanation for that? seems weird...why not `-i src` with a space?

Comment: That's simply the syntax for GHC's arguments